# Can we use MatPaginator in Angular without using the MatTableDataSource/<mat-table>?

Tags: pagination, angular-material, angular8

I am trying to use MatPaginator but with a normal 'table' tag in html instead of 'mat-table'. It didnt seem to work and when I looked up for some references, I found all the examples related to MatPaginator makes use of the MatTableDataSource. Is it compulsory that both should be clubbed and used for the pagination to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MatTableDataSource` is aimed to be used for filtering, sorting and pagination of a client-side data array. In cases where filtering, sorting and pagination are done server-side, the use of this class is not appropriate.

A good example is given at https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-data-table/. It doesn't use `MatTableDataSource` but still uses `mat-table`, this should however be easily adaptable to a normal `HTML table`.